# How to Run Python Script from Remote Machine via Powershell Asynchronously?

Tags: python, function, powershell, parallel-processing, asynchronous

I have a powershell function that only works synchronously. I would like to update this function so that I can fire multiple calls to a Python script in parallel. Does anybody have any insight how to call a Python script asynchronously using powershell keeping in mind that each Python Script is essentially a while loop that doesn't end until 24 hours passes. The powershell function takes in a remote machine, python virtual environment, path to the python script and the arguments.

Here's what has been done so far:

```
function Run-Remote($computerName, $pname, $scriptPath, $pargs)
{
    $cred = Get-QRemote-Credential
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {powershell -c "$Using:pname '$Using:scriptPath' $Using:pargs"} -ConfigurationName QRemoteConfiguration
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple fix, just add "-AsJob" to the invoke command. This will get powershell to spin up a new process for each command that you send. Then Use "Get-Job | Wait-Job" at the end of the script to wait for all the processes to finish. And "Get-Job | Receive-Job" to get any data back.

I recommend reading about powershell jobs they are supper useful but unintuitive.

```
function Run-Remote($computerName, $pname, $scriptPath, $pargs)
{
    $cred = Get-QRemote-Credential
    Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {powershell -c "$Using:pname '$Using:scriptPath' $Using:pargs"} -ConfigurationName QRemoteConfiguration
}

Get-Job | Wait-Job
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried using AsJob parameter, but it didn't generate a python process in the task machine.

Comment: That's very odd, did the job complete properly? The only thing I can think of is is the script exited before the job completed

Comment: it did not. I used -indisconnectedsession instead. Do you foresee any issues with using that instead?